# Stream Stream Join Spark Structure Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Below is the use case for Spark Structure Streaming

Step 1:
StreamA = loaded from Kafka topicA containing event of type A

Step 2:
StreamB = loaded from Kafka topicB containing event of type B

Step 3:
JoinedStream = StreamA inner join StreamB on id

Step 4:
Insert matched data into Database

I don't need matched data for further processing. Will Spark stream clear the state on joining ?

If not how do I clear them without watermark?

Answer (score 0):

For inner join although watermark and join conditions are optional as per the doc (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#inner-joins-with-optional-watermarking)

> To avoid unbounded state, you have to define additional join
> conditions such that indefinitely old inputs cannot match with future
> inputs and therefore can be cleared from the state. In other words,
> you will have to do the following additional steps in the join

Any reason not to include watermark and conditions to clear off the state?